# keyboard interrupt doesn't stop my interpreter

Tags: python, terminal, osx-lion, infinite-loop

I am testing a Log-parser that does a infinite loop (on purpose) with a cool down of 3 seconds every recurrence.

Eventually I will link all the data to a GUI front-end so I can call a stop to the loop when the user is ready with parsing.

The (small) problem now is, when testing the output in the Terminal (in OSX) when I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to cancel the process my activity monitor keeps showing the process as active (probably because of the loop?).

So the question: How can I call (without extra non-native libraries, if possible) to stop the whole process when calling a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in Terminal? When I quit the Terminal, all python processes get killed, but I would like to know how to do it while the Terminal is still running :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> sends to background, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is to kill. However I am talking Linux here and Mac might be something different.

Comment: Lol, I feel so dumb now, haha. Yes that works on OSX too :). The OSX Terminal is the same as other UNIX Terminals (excepting a few OS specific features). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/124367/35504 suggests that this works as stated on OSX. (I don't know for sure, either).